# M1 MacBook Pro disconnects USB keyboard on sleep, needs restart

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, sleep-wake, apple-silicon

*MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)*

My keyboard usually looks like this in System Report:

> [image: USB 3.1 Bus with hubs and keyboards connected]

After sleeping, the MacBook can't see any USB devices.

> [image: USB 3.1 Bus with no devices connected]

Unplugging and replugging the USB hub does not fix it. I have to restart the system to get it back.

Comment: Have you disconnected manually before letting the mac sleep?

Comment: A different USB-C to -A adapter doesn't seem to have the problem. The one that does have the problem is a generic:    "USB C Adapter, EliveBuy 7 in 1 Multi Port Dongle USB Hubs Compatible 2018/2017/2016 MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt 3 (40 Gb/s),100W PD, SD Card Reader, 4K HDMI (Space Gray)"

Comment: I also have the same problem (Same view on System Report) on the sam MBP version. OP: have you had any luck in fixing this?